# QT Moving entire window/application by clicking on the menubar c++

Tags: c++, qt

I want to get rid of the my application's title and border, but to do that I need to be able to move the window by dragging on the menuBar. The two  method's I've found to do this is:

```
void TopMenuBar::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        dragPosition = event->globalPos() - frameGeometry().topLeft();
        event->accept();
    }
}

void TopMenuBar::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        move(event->globalPos() - dragPosition);
        event->accept();
    }
}
```

However if I put this in the MainWindow, it will move around no matter what you click on, and if I put it in a custom QMenuBar, it only moves the menubar within the window. I've also attempted to do some signals and slots trickery between the objects (Like keeping mousePressEvent in menuBar and mouseMoveEvent in MainWindow), but the tendency is that the window will "jump" to where the mouse pointer is instead of moving it smoothly.

Anyone else have a solution for this?

Environment is Windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move a window by clicking an internal widget instead of title bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818192/move-a-window-by-clicking-an-internal-widget-instead-of-title-bar)

Comment: You need to use [`window()->move()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#window) to move the whole window's widget.

Comment: window()->move() makes the whole window "jump" to the mouse position, which is not a wanted feature. You should be able to drag it around smoothly

Comment: This is not true.Try running the example code in the question I have linked, The window does **not** *"jump" to the mouse position*. It moves as smoothly as when using the native title bar. This maybe another problem in your code.

Comment: You're right. I apologise. There are differences in how the mouse position compared to the window is calculated in the code you linked to compared to what I used. It is possible it will work like that. However Leontyev's answer below works excellently as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for certain - just checked it. Call **ui->menuBar->installEventFilter(this);** in the MainWindow constructor.

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if (watched == ui->menuBar)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
        {
            QMouseEvent* mouse_event = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
            if (mouse_event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
            {
                dragPosition = mouse_event->globalPos() - frameGeometry().topLeft();
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
        {
            QMouseEvent* mouse_event = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
            if (mouse_event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
            {
                move(mouse_event->globalPos() - dragPosition);
                return false;
            }
        }


    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: false is always returned to let those widgets in the menu bar to be properly pressed without interruption by the event filter.

Comment: This works! Doesn't even require custom menubar class. Thanks a bunch!